# How to draw BIG thin text in android

Tags: android, graphic

I need to draw single character on my view as BIG thin text as shown in image below (text as just simple lines)

[image]

But my code below gives me following image (text as shape)

```
    Paint dPaint = new Paint();
    dPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    dPaint.setDither(true);
    dPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    dPaint.setTextSize(getWidth()*.8F);
    dPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    dPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);
    canvas.drawText("A",getWidth()*.3F, getHeight()*.6F, dPaint);
```

[image]

I tried various paint and stroke properties but none worked out. Also I read the in java 2D text is drawn as shape.

Is there a way to draw text (character in particular) as lines rather then shape. Also text down should be BIG in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only two ways to achieve your requirement.

Use a custom font-type with your font style and use it in your application as below

```
    TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "ThinText.ttf");
    text.setTypeface(customFont);
```

Another technique is you have to draw the shape of give character as lines by calculating the coordinates required in the path to draw that alphabet or digit.

I hope it may help you.

Comment: Thought it still paint character as shape, but thin text font gave the illusion of line. I found a thin text font [here](http://www.dafont.com/bird-cherry.font)

Answer (score 0):

You increase `strokewidth`, then thin is increased like so:

```
dPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
```

Comment: But character still get's drawn as shape, not as lines. Which is real challenge.