# Java : how to get shape of character (not outline)

Tags: java, graphics, shapes, glyph

Is there any way to get the "shape" representing a character using Java.

I know about the getOutling() of the GlyphVector class. But it returns the outline of the character.

What I require is not the outline, but a single line shape depicting the character.

Comment: Characters are defined by their outlines. The information that you're looking for is not present in the font data.

Comment: You could take a look at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/OutlineFontpaint.htm

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9043947) some time back. Because characters are only defined by there area (outline), may be you can use a thin font and get the Outline and use it as shape.

Comment: I need to draw some specific art along the path of the text so that it appears that the whole text is made up of that art only. The outline shape wont be ok. I believe that even the thin fonts will give me an outline which shall consist of 2 shapes combined (inner shape +outer shape)

Comment: Did you at least try with thin font, may be two overlapping art are fine!